# Use tr or sed to swap values

Tags: bash, sed, tr

I have a file where I want to change values `/1` to `/2`, and `/2` to `/1`

I have tried

```
cat file.txt | tr /1 /2 > out.txt
```

Problem is this simply leaves me with all /2, and if I try to do:

```
cat file.txt | tr /1 /2 | tr /2 /1 > out.txt
```

then I get all /1's. How can I swap the two numbers at the same time?

I have also just tried this but no luck

```
sed -i -e 's/\/1/\/2/g' -e 's/\/2/\/1/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
perl -pe 's|/(\d+)|$1 == 1 ? "/2" : "/1"|ge' file
```